# How do i change the order of my activities starting up?

Tags: android, android-layout, splash-screen

I am completely new to android studios and have no idea how to change the order of my activities starting up so that it will be in the order of Splash Screen > Homepage > MainActivity, here's my android manifest, as it keeps going straight from the splash screen to the MainActivity, skipping the Homepage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sg.edu.tp.moviereviewapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".splash_screen"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Homepage" />
        <activity android:name=".Signup" />
        <activity android:name=".Forgot_password" />
        <activity android:name=".avengers_into" />
        <activity android:name=".now_showing" />
        <activity android:name=".trending" />
        <activity android:name=".upcoming" />
        <activity android:name=".blackpanther_into" />
        <activity android:name=".greatestshowman_into" />
        <activity android:name=".reviewspage" />
        <activity android:name=".leave_a_review" />
        <activity android:name=".thanks" />
    enter code here
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Which activity leads to which is not defined in the Maifest. Switching activities happens by calling `startActivity()` in the Java Code.

Answer (score 0):

The code to start next activity (i.e. `Homepage` or `MainActivity` or whatever) is inside the `Splash` activity because by default your `Splash` activity is the starting point and from that point(once you see splash activity), you(your code) handles the flow(not manifest).

So look for

```
// must be explicit intent due to no intent filters
Intent someName = new intent(Splash.this, HomeActivity.class);
```

and change it to

```
Intent someName = new intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: i am glad that i could help, happy coding!